# Insert a variable into NSMutableArray Object

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, iphone

I would like to add a predefined string to the object of an NSMutableArray.  I thought you would use `%@`, but apparently the code below does not execute well.  Thank You in advance

```
arrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
               initWithObjects:@"%@ you look tired." name,
                               @"Why do you smell so bad?",
                               @"I have to go potty!",
                               @"%@ put your pants on!" name,
                               @"Mommy!",
                               @"Daddy!",
                               @"NOOOOOO!",
                               @"When are we going to get there?",
                               @"I HATE YOU!",
                               nil];
```

Comment: Whenever you do a format string, put a comma between it and the variables you are substituting. Above, you should have ... @"you look tired", name ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%@` is valid inside a `stringWithFormat:` call. Your code should look something like this:

```
arrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ you look tired.", name],
                  @"Why do you smell so bad?",
                  @"I have to go potty!",
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ put your pants on!", name],
                  @"Mommy!",
                  @"Daddy!",
                  @"NOOOOOO!",
                  @"When are we going to get there?",
                  @"I HATE YOU!",
                  nil];
```